# Add and Reporting Data to/from a dictionary errors

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, while-loop

Program has user input a State Abbreviation and then it's Capital.

If the dictionary already contains the State that the user input then it needs to report it's capital while continuing the loop to have users input States and their Capitals.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to have the program report back the Capital and then continue the loop. It just prints the state and capital infinitely.

```py
def main():
    
    sc=  {'FL':'Tallahassee',
          'AK':'Juneau',
          'AZ':'Phoenix',
          'CA':'Sacramento',}
    count(sc)
    print("Let's add a few more")
    state=input('Enter a States Abbreviation or Enter to quit:')
   
    while state !='':
        if state in sc:
            print(f'Already have {state}. Its Capital is',sc.get(f'{state}'))
        
        if state not in sc:
            capital=input('Enter that States Capital:')
            sc[state]=capital      
            state=input('Enter a States Abbreviation or Enter to quit:')
        

          
        
    sc_len=len(sc)
    print(f'Got {sc_len} States now. Here they are...')
    for key,value in sc.items():
        print('The capital of',key,'is',value)


main()
```

Comment: Have you tried to add your first  `state = input (' ....')` into your while loop? This way you would be able to reset the `state` variable causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Hi HakunaMutata, I've answered question. Please take a look at it, and I'm looking forward for your response 

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to remove the line,

```py
state=input('Enter a States Abbreviation or Enter to quit:')
```

from the `if-statement` block and move it to the `while` block, like this:

```py
while state !='':
        if state in sc:
            print(f'Already have {state}. Its Capital is',sc.get(f'{state}'))
        
        if state not in sc:
            capital=input('Enter that States Capital:')
            sc[state]=capital 
                 
        state=input('Enter a States Abbreviation or Enter to quit:')    # <----
```

Now even if the `state` is in the `sc`, it will ask for another state afterwards, and it won't stuck in an infinity loop.

---

**Result:**

[image]